# Is it possible to get the name of all files in a directory that start with a certain string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate

I am trying to get the names of all files in a directory whose names start with *abc*.So far I have tried this but it does'nt work.

```
 NSString *bundleRoot = path;
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self STARTSWITH '_abc_'"];
    NSArray *onlyJPGs = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
```

I am getting the following exception

```
Unable to parse the format string "self STARTSWITH '_store_'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string comparison operator in a predicate is "BEGINSWITH", not "STARTSWITH":

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH %@", @"abc"];
```

And using a format `%@` for the right-hand side works correctly even if the string
contains special characters like `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) there is no `STARTSWITH` predicate. Try `BEGINSWITH` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

NSString *attributeName = @"firstName";

NSString *attributeValue = @"Adam";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",

```
    attributeName, attributeValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

search first with BEGINSWITH for "Foo", this will find you the beginnings of a string

"Foo Word1 Word2", "Foo OtherWord1 OtherWord2" (will find 2)
and than CONTAINS for " Foo" (note the space before Foo), which will give you words that starts with "Foo" presided with a space

"Word1 Foo Word", "Some OtherWord FooWord", "Misc    FooXWord" (will find 3)
Predicate :

> NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
>                             @"(content BEGINSWITH[c] %@) OR (content CONTAINS[c] %@)", word, [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", word]];